# Firefox - "Block All Cookies" is not working

Tags: firefox, cookies, http-headers

### I am testing how Web sites respond to cookies being disabled in Firefox. I disabled cookies in Firefox using the "All third-party cookies" setting (see screenshot):

[image]

### Next I checked the request headers in the Firefox debug console to make sure no cookies were being sent, however it appears that Firefox is still sending the "Cookie" header (see screenshot):

[image]

### What is going on here?